# rmdir and rm -rf fail with Directory not empty, no hidden files; -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) from strace of ls

Tags: linux, rm, strace

On a RHEL 6.10 server there is a mounted NAS where I can't delete directories with neither `rm -rf` nor `rmdir`. Both fail with `rm: cannot remove "backup/backup.1": Directory not empty`. I made sure to use `ls -ali`, and tried  `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` with `rmdir`. [I saw the suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417141/180291) to `strace` the `ls` and here's what I get:

```
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "rsync-test/backup/backup.4/"], [/* 29 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x12e2000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3728926000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=49961, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 49961, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3728919000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0PY`,1\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=124640, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x312c600000, 2221912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x312c600000
mprotect(0x312c61d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x312c81c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x312c81c000
mmap(0x312c81e000, 1880, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x312c81e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240!\340+1\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47760, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x312be00000, 2128816, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x312be00000
mprotect(0x312be07000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x312c006000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x312c006000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\23`11\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19016, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3728918000
mmap(0x3131600000, 2111776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3131600000
mprotect(0x3131604000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3131803000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x3131803000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\36\34001\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=33816, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3130e00000, 2126416, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3130e00000
mprotect(0x3130e07000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3131006000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x3131006000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\356\1\2237\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1930416, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3793000000, 3750184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3793000000
mprotect(0x379318b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x379338a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18a000) = 0x379338a000
mmap(0x3793390000, 14632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3793390000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r@\2237\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=23088, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3728917000
mmap(0x3793400000, 2109696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3793400000
mprotect(0x3793402000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3793602000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x3793602000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000^`+1\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=146592, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x312b600000, 2212848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x312b600000
mprotect(0x312b617000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x312b817000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x312b817000
mmap(0x312b819000, 13296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x312b819000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY)   = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\23`.1\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=21152, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x312e600000, 2113888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x312e600000
mprotect(0x312e604000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x312e803000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x312e803000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3728916000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3728914000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f37289147a0) = 0
mprotect(0x312c81c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x312c006000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3131006000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x379338a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3793602000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3792e20000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x312b817000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x312e803000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f3728919000, 49961)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f3728914a70)         = 37574
set_robust_list(0x7f3728914a80, 24)     = 0
futex(0x7ffca56b8aec, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7ffca56b8aec, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7f37289147a0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x312b605cb0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x312b60f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x312b605d40, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x312b60f7e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=10240*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/selinux", {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=7708159, f_bfree=6845829, f_bavail=6452613, f_files=1966080, f_ffree=1827695, f_fsid={-881742105, 1365551766}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x12e2000
brk(0x1303000)                          = 0x1303000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3728925000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 1024) = 365
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f3728925000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99170352, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99170352, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3722a80000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=59, ws_col=194, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
stat("rsync-test/backup/backup.4/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}) = 0
open("rsync-test/backup/backup.4/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3728925000
write(1, "Thesis\n", 7)                 = 7
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f3728925000, 4096)            = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

And for strace of the rm:

```
execve("/bin/rm", ["rm", "-rf", "backup"], [/* 29 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x116f000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa627552000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=49961, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 49961, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa627545000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\356\1\2237\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1930416, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3793000000, 3750184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3793000000
mprotect(0x379318b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x379338a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18a000) = 0x379338a000
mmap(0x3793390000, 14632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3793390000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa627544000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa627543000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa627542000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fa627543700) = 0
mprotect(0x379338a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3792e20000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fa627545000, 49961)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x116f000
brk(0x1190000)                          = 0x1190000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99170352, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99170352, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6216ae000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
lstat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "backup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1960, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "backup", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1960, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x18800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
mmap(NULL, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa62168d000
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 7 entries */, 131072)    = 208
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 131072)    = 0
munmap(0x7fa62168d000, 135168)          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(4, "backup.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "backup.1", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x18800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
brk(0x11b2000)                          = 0x11b2000
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 5
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, 0x1171b10, 131072)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
unlinkat(4, "backup.1", AT_REMOVEDIR)   = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2512, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6216ad000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2512
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa6216ad000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=435, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 435, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6216ad000
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "rm: ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "cannot remove `backup/backup.1'", 31) = 31
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Directory not empty", 21)   = 21
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
newfstatat(4, "backup.2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "backup.2", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x18800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 5
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, 0x1173290, 131072)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
unlinkat(4, "backup.2", AT_REMOVEDIR)   = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
write(2, "rm: ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "cannot remove `backup/backup.2'", 31) = 31
write(2, ": Directory not empty", 21)   = 21
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
newfstatat(4, "backup.3", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "backup.3", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x18800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 5
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, 0x1173290, 131072)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
unlinkat(4, "backup.3", AT_REMOVEDIR)   = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
write(2, "rm: ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "cannot remove `backup/backup.3'", 31) = 31
write(2, ": Directory not empty", 21)   = 21
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
newfstatat(4, "backup.4", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "backup.4", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x18800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 5
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 131072)    = 80
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 131072)    = 0
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(5, "Thesis", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(5, "Thesis", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=840, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x18800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 131072)    = 80
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 131072)    = 0
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(6, "notebook", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=1120, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(6, "notebook", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=1120, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x18800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 7
fcntl(7, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, 0x1173290, 131072)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
unlinkat(6, "notebook", AT_REMOVEDIR)   = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
write(2, "rm: ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "cannot remove `backup/backup.4/T"..., 47) = 47
write(2, ": Directory not empty", 21)   = 21
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
close(6)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
newfstatat(4, "backup.6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=1120, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "backup.6", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=1120, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x18800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(3, F_DUPFD, 3)                    = 5
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, 0x1173290, 131072)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
unlinkat(4, "backup.6", AT_REMOVEDIR)   = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
write(2, "rm: ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "cannot remove `backup/backup.6'", 31) = 31
write(2, ": Directory not empty", 21)   = 21
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
close(4)                                = 0
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Does  `unlinkat(4, "backup.6", AT_REMOVEDIR)   = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)` provide any clues?

Answer (score 0):

***Warning*** It seems like you are attempting to delete backup files. I would recommend being careful. If you are using a mature device, there might be documentation on managing (modifying/deleting/resizing) back up files. If there is confusing documentation, you can post about them.

When using rm -rf, be sure to specify the directory i.e. rm -rf backup/

Make sure you have the permissions to remove the file.

Try running lsof on the file you are having trouble with. Under the FD column you should be able to see if there are any file descriptor associated with that backup. You may also be able to find a PID associated with that file. You could then close the file descriptor associated with the resource or kill the process associated with that file.

Comment: Well, there are no files to delete. Only directories. So I tried `lsof` with the `+D` option, and nothing. I can delete other files/directories just not these which are empty directories. Yes these are backups so space isn't the issue it's just for others who may see these and wonder what they are for.